# Datbinding element in list to an item outside of the list

Tags: xaml, data-binding

I'm using XAML for a windows phone apps, and I'm binding a collection to  graph control within the listbox Itemtemplate.    Everything shows correctly except that the Horizontal axis is scaled per the data in the grid and I want them all scaled the same.

I've worked out the Maximum value - which need to establish the data binding - as its in a listbox itemtemplate I can't simply set the value in code.    And for the data binding I only seem to see the elements in the collection but the value I have is not an element of the collection.

Is it possible to bind to a property/field of the page - that way I can set the value and all the grids can just bind to this property/fields.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to bind element inside `ListBox` item template to property of the page is by using `ElementName` binding. Simply name the page, then you can set binding source by page name, for example :

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    ..........
    ..........
    x:Name="myPage">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=myPage, Path=Name}" />
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Above sample will display text "myPage" in the TextBlock. That way of binding also works for elements inside `DataTemplate` for `ListBox` item.